# C++: Method of calling functions whose parameter list was parsed from a text file

Tags: c++, callback, parameter-passing, boost-bind

I'm looking to allow functions within my programme to be called from text file that is somewhat like a script.

I'd like to be able to register any function with this "script manager" without forcing it to conform to some specific signature. Hence being able to call from the script: MyFunc(bool, string) or MyFunc2(int, float, char). On the parsing side I can put these parameters into a parameter list but the problem is how can I pass these parameters to the function?

I cannot call it like MyFunc(paramlist[0], paramlist[1]) since that forces a specific signature. I also do not want the functions being called to be required to know about "script manager" and thus they should not need to be able to handle the parameter lists.

How can I decouple these two components (the functions being called and the "script manager") without writing some wrapper around the former (the functions being called)?

Comment: The solutions are going to be about how to invent a dynamic type system. I recommend looking into a dynamic language that you can hook up with C++, that way all the dirty work has *already* been done. I personally recommend Lua, with or without Luabind, but there are other possibilities.

Comment: Unless you really need a custom scripting language, it's better if you use one that's already available. Look into Python and the Python C-API or Boost.Python, for example. Read about the pros and cons of various scripting languages like Python and Lua, and decide which one best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do stuff like that yourself, but I think that it is better just to use Lua (http://lua.org ). Lua integrates greatly with c/c++ programs and there is a lot of comprehensive documentation and tutorials available; for example, have a look at this one: http://csl.sublevel3.org/lua/ (pay attention to the section "calling C functions from Lua", this is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

As others, I recommend that you do not reinvent the wheel if you can avoid it. That is, use an existing framework if you can. But I am going to extend a little bit into a possible solution.

C++ does not have reflection, which means that you cannot, at runtime, accept a function pointer, inspect it and interpret what the arguments are. But you can do that at compile time. The solution will not be simple, but it can be done with type erasure. To simplify the problem, I will assume that all functions return `void` it is complex enough like that.

In one potential solution the dispatcher structure may look like (errors being ignored):

```
while (true) {
   std::string func = read_function_name();
   std::vector<parameter_t> params = read_parameters();
   functions[ func ]( params );
}
```

Now to fill in the blanks: `read_function_name` is a simple function that returns the name of the function to call. Not the function, just the name. `read_parameters` is a function that processes the input file and builds a sequence of *parameters* to be passed to the function. `functions` is an associative container that maps a function name to one of our functions. The parameters are some sort of *type erasure* of the actual parameter types, so that we can manage them generically in a single container. Our functions are instances of a class that that implements an `operator()` that takes one sequence of parameters and performs type erasure on the exact function to call. That was simple! At least if you ignore the details.

Implementation of parameters is not too complex, you could just use `boost::any` and hope for the best, or you could implement your own type erasure with a bit more information so that you can perform better error detection, or implicit conversions or... you name it.

Implementation of the `function_t` type is a bit more complex. We need to perform type erasure on the actual element that is callable, and `std::function<>` fits the problem up to here. But we cannot use it because that will leave us with the smallest possible interface for a function: `operator()` *you know the parameters*, and what we have is `operator()` *who knows the parameters*?

This is where most of the work is to be done, and were you will need manual type erasure. That can be implemented by a base abstract class `function_base` that offers a `virtual operator()( std::vector<parameter_t> [const] & ) [const]` (play with const-ness or forget about it for the time being to simplify a bit the problem). The `function_t` will just hold a pointer to that base type, and perform the call. Up to here still simple.

Implementation of type erasure for the functions... Now the next problem is how to implement each concrete derived type from `function_base`, and there is where things get a bit trickier (we agreed the rest was simple, didn't we?) You need to provide a constructor template in `function_t` that will take *any* function, instantiate a templated type derived from `function_base` and store the pointer inside the `function_t`.

Again to avoid complexity, assume that you can do with a single argument. The rest is just more code... The implementation of `function_impl<>` just needs to store the original function pointer, and remember the type and number (in this case 1) of arguments. The implementation of `operator()` iterates the vector of parameters and for each parameter it unerases the type (converts back to the original type) and calls the function. This code will have to be pretty much manual in the template, but it will be reusable for all of the functions of the same arity.

To make things a bit simpler here you can make use of function traits libraries, that will be able to extract the type and number of arguments from the function that you receive.

So what is left for user code? That is simple, and in this case I mean it. Your interface should offer `function_t`, which can be constructed from *any* function pointer (as long as it fits the requirements of what you managed to implement there), and a function to register any such `function_t` in your system by providing a name:

```
// user code: registration of a new function
void print_single_int( int );
lib::function_t f( &print_single_int );
lib::register( "print_single_int", f );
```

Those two lines will have to be typed for each function that you want to add to your system. Of course, you might decide that the *complexity* of the solution does not compensate the problem and go for a manual implementation, were user code just creates hand coded derivations of `function_base` that manually process the vector of parameters and calls the function... if there are few operations that you want to implement in your scripting language, it might not be worth the extra effort of making it generic.